# Entity Framework Core 7 Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a Foreign Key "string ParamName" in my entity, it refers to ParamDesc entity. How can I make this foreign key not strict? I mean, I want my foreign key can contain any values, even that not refer to any ParamDesc entity. Thank you in advance.

I have tried:

```
modelBuilder
                .Entity<ParamInfo>()
                .HasOne(pi => pi.ParamDesc)
                .WithMany(e => e.ParamInfos)
                .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.ParamName)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

I still cannot add ParamInfo with unknown ParamName, but I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, I want my foreign key can contain any values, even that not refer to any ParamDesc entity

Then it is not a foreign key and should not be one. That is not a strict EF Core rule but the definition of foreign key in relational databases:

From [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16):

> A foreign key (FK) is a column or combination of columns that is used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables to control the data that can be stored in the foreign key table.

Or [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

> A foreign key is a set of attributes in a table that refers to the primary key of another table. The foreign key links these two tables. Another way to put it: In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a set of attributes subject to a certain kind of inclusion dependency constraints, specifically a constraint that the tuples consisting of the foreign key attributes in one relation, R, must also exist in some other (not necessarily distinct) relation, S, and furthermore that those attributes must also be a candidate key in S

So they are used for referential consistency and your column - is not. Either split it in two, one for optional FK ([with optional relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#required-navigations)) and one for the rest of data or add another column which will determine the type of data stored in the first one and use "manual" joins based on that (I would recommend following the first approach).